# asyncio. dynamically add coroutines to loop

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing app, which scans directory every second, checks for new files, and if they appeared - sends them via POST request and performs archiving. Assuming that number of files, which can appear in directory can be from 10 to 100 - I decided to use asyncio and aiohttp, to send requests concurrently.

Code:

```
import os
import aiohttp
from aiohttp.client import ClientSession

BASE_DIR = '/path/to'
ARCHIVE_DIR = '/path/to/archive'

async def scan():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        for file in os.listdir(BASE_DIR):
            if os.path.join(BASE_DIR, file).endswith('jpg'):
                asyncio.ensure_future(publish_file(file))


async def publish_file(file):
    async with ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        async with session.post(url=url, data={'photo': open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, file), 'rb')}) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                await move_to_archive(file)

async def move_to_archive(file):
    os.rename(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, file), os.path.join(ARCHIVE_DIR, file))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

coros = [
    asyncio.ensure_future(scan())
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(coros))
```

So the question is: If i want to send requests concurrent, is this a good practice to add coroutines to loop like this : `asyncio.ensure_future(publish_file(file))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

P.S. Better to share the same session (perhaps with limited amount of parallel connections) than recreate a connection pool on every post request:

```
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=10))
```